# PDOSessionHandler throws "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object" error

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, session, pdo

I've implemented `PdoSessionHandler` in order to save sessions in my MySQL database [as described in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html):

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    session:
        handler_id:      session.handler.pdo
```

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    session.handler.pdo:
        class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        public:    false
        arguments:
            - "mysql:host=%database_host%;dbname=%database_name%"
            - { db_table: _sessions, db_username: %database_user%, db_password: %database_password% }
```

This - in general - works fine (sessions are persisted in db), but I'm continuously getting this error:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Error: Call to a member function
prepare() on a non-object" at /srv/www/code/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php
line 331 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 0):
Error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object at /srv/www/code/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php:331)"} []
```

Is this a bug or is my implementation faulty?

Comment: Are there any more log lines to the stack trace? The line it refers to implies that the PDO object for the session handler has been set to null. Does your MySQL server have a short connection timeout (e.g. "Server has gone away"). What situations does this error happen in?

Comment: I'm also encountering this problem, but it is only in production mode (in linux server). The production mode in the local server is fine. Nobody answer?

Comment: I found that it is just a wrong database configuration error in the production server. Resolved!

Comment: Could you eleborate on the settings you changed? Thanks

Comment: @Sithu Yeah, could you post your solution as answer?